# Normal Convergence in Unit Disk

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

As I'm preparing for my qualifying exams, I have been given a question, and I'm not sure how to interpret what is being asked. The text I am using is Complex Analysis by Freitag (although the prompt for the question is from elsewhere). The question is as follows:

Let $f_n$: $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a sequence of holomorphic (analytic) functions in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. Suppose that $f_n(z) \rightarrow 1$ for some $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Prove that $f_n$ converges to 1 normally in $\mathbb{D}$.

From Freitag, I have the definition of normal convergence to be:

A series of functions $f_n$ is called normally convergent in $D$ if for each point $a \in D$, there is a neighborhood $U$ and a sequence $(M_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of non-negative real numbers such that
$$|f_n(z)| \leq M_N \ \text{ for all } \  z \in U \cap D \ \text{ and } \ \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} M_n \ \text{converges}$$

There are a few parts of this problem that I am having difficulty understanding. For one, if I am assuming that $f_n(z) \rightarrow 1$, then my values for $M_n$ will be near 1, and the sum of $M_n$ will not converge. I also thought that it may be ambiguity  on the part of the part of the textbook, and instead here, my definition should suggest that $|f_n(z) - 1| \leq M_n$, in which case this definition seems very close to regular convergence. That, however, seems a little elementary compared to similar problems I've had to work on, making me think that this isn't the case either.

Second, and this may follow from the fact that I don't understand exactly what is being asked, I have no idea how to even begin going about the rest of this problem. Just because I have a sequence of functions converging to a point in the unit disk shouldn't mean that the entire sequence is approaching the constant function $f = 1$, should it?

One thing I have tried to play with is the idea that, since series of functions are mentioned in the same section of Freitag that they mean $f = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n = 1$. If this is the case, then perhaps we can say that in a neighborhood of this point $z$, every value approaches 1, in which case we can use the Identity Theorem for analytic functions, and extend this to show that it must be equal to 1 everywhere.

I seriously appreciate any help or insight that anybody could offer!

Edit: Normal convergence suggests a series, and this is augmented by the fact that previously in my text, we have the definition that a series of functions $f_1 + f_2 + \dots$ is locally uniformly convergent if the sequence $S_n = f_1 + \dots + f_n$ is uniformly convergent. However, as discussed in the comments, would this not suggest that my sequence goes to 0 rather than 1?

I would also like to add that I'm not sure what is meant in the question prompt $f_n \rightarrow 1$. This could be pointwise or uniform, although both of these contradict our assumption that any series with these $f_n$ would converge.

Part of the ambiguity may come from the fact that different schools and texts are familiar with slightly different definitions for terminology. For example, in my course, we almost always used the term analytic rather than holomorphic. This particular problem comes from Texas A&M Complex Analysis Qualifying Exam, Fall 2014, Problem 9 - http://www.math.tamu.edu/graduate/phd/quals.html

Comment: Definitely there is an issue; whether it is with the wording of the problem or the wording of the definition, I don't know. What is the source for the prompt? I haven't heard the terminology for normally convergent before, so it seems possible there isn't a standard convention for the definition.

Comment: Normal convergence likely means uniform convergence here. Only series can converge normally. You are certainly asked to prove that: $$\sup_{z\in\mathbb{D}}|f_n(z)-1|\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$$

Comment: The key point is that the functions are functions $f_n : \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$, not $f_n : \Bbb D \to \Bbb C$. In particular, you have that $\forall z\in \Bbb D, \forall n, |f_n(z)| < 1$. It's then clear that if $f_n$ converge to an holomorphic function $f$, then $f \equiv 1$ by the maximum principle (1 would be a maximum, and inside the domain). Now, I'm not sure how to show that $f_n$ converge necessarily to an holomorphic function

Comment: @C.Falcon I agree that only a series can converge normally, which is what prompted my guess that the sum of my sequence of functions $f_n$ is what converges to $f$. I'll add this as an edit to the question, amother given in my text suggesting that this may be the case (and it not being uniform convergent) is we have that a series of functions $f_n$ is uniformly convergent if the sequence $S_n = f_1 + \dots + f_n$ is uniformly convergent. However, this doesn't come up at all in the definition of normal convergence. Further...

Comment: @C.Falcon Further, there is a Weierstrass majorant test that states that a normally convergent series of functions converges uniformly. But if we have a series of functions that converges uniformly, would it not necessarily be the case that $f_n \rightarrow 0$? This seems contrary to the question prompt

Comment: @Tryss This is a very good point, actually, stating that the modulus of each of my $f_n$ terms is going to be bounded by 1. This is currently the longest piece of thread that I have to pull on, and going about showing that this will converge to a holomorphic function seems like my best bet. I'm going to discuss it with my class this morning, and I'll report back. Thank you for this piece of insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $f_n$ are uniformly bounded, Montel's theorem says the $f_n$ form a normal family.  Therefore every subsequence has a sub-subsequence that converges normally (i.e. uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb D$) to a holomorphic function $h$ on $\mathbb D$.  But by the Maximum Modulus 
Principle, $h$ is identically $1$.  Now if $f_n$ didn't converge normally to $1$, there would be a compact subset $K$ on which $f_n$ didn't converge uniformly to $1$, and then some $\epsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $f_{n_j}$ such that $\sup_{z\in K} |f_{n_j}(z)-1| > \epsilon$; and then no sub-subsequence could converge uniformly to $1$ on $K$.

Comment: This ended up being golden. I've given up on tying in the exact definition of normal convergence, but I believe this is in the spirit of the problem. I can't begin to thank you enough for your help! My only question to this would be - after showing that we converge normally to $h$, would it still be necessary to continue forward with the contradiction?